# не ставится prisma

Tags: postgresql, docker, prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String @unique
}
---------------схема


version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db:
--------------docker


DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?schema=public"
------------------env

---------------------ошибка
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настроил psql заново и все заработало

Comment: Подскажи что именно делал, у меня тоже такая ошибка